# Remove section of text using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I remove a section of text between [Start] and [End] from a string block including the tags?

Is there an easier way rather than using `IndexOf` and `Substring` etc?

Update: I'm attempting to use

```
var output = Regex.Replace("[Start]SomeText[End]", @"(?<=[Start]).*(?=[End])", "");
```

But the pattern does not quite work. It needs to remove everything between [Start] and [End]

Input Text:
[Start] Hello World [End]

Output Text:
[Start][End]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\[Start])(?s).+?(?=\[End])");
string output = rgx.Replace(input, "");
```

or this that will be faster:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\[Start])(?>[^[]+|\[(?!End]))+(?=\[End])");
string output = rgx.Replace(input, "");
```

Comment: Why is the second faster?

Comment: @Amicable: Because the first use a lazy quantifier and must check at each character if there is `[End]` after. The second must check if there is `End]` after, only if the character encountered is `[`

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `]` are special characters in regexes.

```
var output =
   Regex.Replace("[Start]SomeText[End]", @"(?<=\[Start\]).*(?=\[End\])", "");
```

Comment: Care to explain - can you give an example where it doesn't work as you would expect (and what your desired outcome is)?

Comment: Updated, I thought you wanted to 'remove a section of text (...) including the tags'